# How to select row which a certain text format?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for an unclear question coz I don't know how to ask correctly. Let me explain this. I'd like to search for some rows in mySQL. Which is only in this format - "product1" (text and number). While in my table. There're some other rows begins with "product" as well. But they're not followed by number.

Here's my table.

```
**product_db**
    +----------+-------+
    |    key   | value |
    +----------+-------+
    | product1 |  100  |
    +----------+-------+
    | product2 |  184  |
    +----------+-------+
    | product3 |  170  |
    +----------+-------+
    | productA |  210  |
    +----------+-------+
    | productB |  100  |
    +----------+-------+
```

This is mySQL:

```
select * from product_db where key like 'product%'
```

After run the code. Every row shows up. Because they're all begins with "product". **I expect only the first 3 rows that followed by number to be displayed**. How can I write a command in mySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [**regex**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
select * from product_db where key REGEXP '^product[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: It's near. But another problem occured. In my real table there're some other rows in this format as well. For example - item1, item2, item3. And when I run your code `select * from product_db where key REGEXP '[product][0-9]+$';`. Those "itemX" shows up too!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'product1' REGEXP '[product][0-9]';
+------------------------------------+
| 'product1' REGEXP '[product][0-9]' |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  1 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

SELECT 'productA' REGEXP '[product][0-9]';
+------------------------------------+
| 'productA' REGEXP '[product][0-9]' |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  0 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```